# Utilizando beecrowd para compilar y evaluar, me dice que el 100% está incorrecto, ¿por qué?

Tags: c++

Estoy ocupando beecrowd para compilar y que sirva de juez a la hora de evaluar, pero me dice que el 100% está incorrecto, ¿por qué? (C++17)

> Juancito quiere calcular y mostrar la cantidad de litros de combustible gastado en un viaje, con un auto que hace 12 Km/L. Para eso, le gustaría que lo ayudes a través de un programa sencillo.
> Para realizar el cálculo, tienes que leer el tiempo (en horas) y la velocidad media (en Km/h) del viaje.
> De esta forma se puede obtener la distancia, y luego, calcular la cantidad de litros necesarios. Mostrar el valor con tres dígitos luego del punto decimal.
> La entrada: contiene dos enteros. El primero es el tiempo que duró el viaje (en horas). El segundo es la velocidad media del viaje (en Km/h).
> Salida: Imprimir cuantos litros de combustible fueron necesarios para hacer el viaje, con tres dígitos luegos del punto decimal.

```
int tiempo, velocidad_media;
float distancia, final;

cout << "Digite la duracion del viaje en horas:" << endl; cin >> tiempo;
cout << "Digite la velocidad media del viaje en km/h:"; cin >> velocidad_media;

distancia = (tiempo*velocidad_media);
final = (distancia/12);

cout.precision(5);
cout << final << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Solo veo código y un enunciado.

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error en particular?

Comment: Todo indica que beecrowd espera poder ingresar y recibir los datos de otra forma que no conocemos... supongo que estás aquí https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/es/problems/view/1017

Comment: Si @Alfabravo es ese mismo problema, la cosa es que puedo compilar y resolver sin errores en sí el problema, pero a la hora de introducirlo en beecrowd me dice que hay errores en la sintaxis, pero el código funcional, no entiendo que puede tener de malo la sintaxis.

Comment: @padaleiana mira mi comentario anterior

Comment: No es posible registrarse en el sitio. Desde afuera no sabría dar una respuesta...

Comment: Más bien, pulsa en [edit] y muestra los errores de sintaxis que dices que muestra la plataforma, _como texto, con formato_.